# How to remove checked attr on a checkbox when I click it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do this : `$(".continuar").removeClass("ver");` when I click one checkbox but I click it again to remove the checked?

I mean when I click one checkbox the button next appears and if I click the second checkbox it changes to checked but I want this : when I click the first or second checkbox again to uncheck I want the button to disappear.

This is exactly what I want: check box 1 unchecked = $(".continuar").addClass("ver"); and the same on check box 2 unchecked = $(".continuar").addClass("ver");

I'm talking about this button

```html
<div class='continuar'>
    <input type="button" onclick="siguiente()" value="Continuar" class="boton" />
</div>
<input class="opc1" type="checkbox" value="1" onClick="Califica(1)" />
<input class="opc2" type="checkbox" value="2" onClick="Califica(2)" />
```

```js
function Califica(opc) {
    $(".continuar").addClass("ver");
    respuestas[pMin]=opc;

    if (opc==1) {
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', true);
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', false);
    } else if (opc==2) {
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', true );
    } else if(opc == 1 || opc == 2) {
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").removeAttr('checked');
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").removeAttr('checked');
     }
}
```

I tried to do this with Netzach comment but it didn't work

function Califica(opc){

```
    $(".continuar").addClass("ver");
    respuestas[pMin]=opc;
    if (opc==1){
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', true); 
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', false);
        $('.opc1').on("click",function(){



if($(this).attr('checked')) { 
$('.button').show();
 }else{
   $('.button').hide();
  }
});

    }else if (opc==2){
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc1").attr('checked', false);
        $("#p"+pMin+" .respuesta .opciones .opc2").attr('checked', true );  
        $('.opc2').on("click",function(){


 if($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $('#button').hide();
  }
});     
        }
        }
```

Comment: Side note:  How would the final else if condition ever be reached?

Comment: Please clarify - you intend for one action to occur on the first click (remove class) and then a second action to occur on the second click (uncheck checkbox).  What should happen on the third and subsequent clicks?

Comment: on the first click I want to check the checkbox because the button will appear but on second click I want to remove the button

Comment: what button you want remove?

Comment: @asd i am currently unclear of what you are asking, but i believe many SO users and myself can help you with your problem.  if you could clarify what you want to implement by organizing your question as follows, we'd be happy to help you out: "check box 1 checked = what functionality, check box 1 unchecked = what functionality, checkbox 2 checked = what functionality, checkbox 2 unchecked = what functionality, and any combination case of the checkboxes that alters functionality". thanks.

Comment: <div class='continuar' ><input type="button" onclick="siguiente()" value="Continuar"  class="boton" > </div>   that button

Comment: First of all thanks to all that want to help me and of course brother I want only the check box 1 unchecked and checkbox 2 unchecked and this is exactly:   check box 1 unchecked = $(".continuar").addClass("ver"); and the same on check box 2 unchecked = $(".continuar").addClass("ver");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click an input, you need know if is checked or not.
Your button init $('#button').hide(); or display:none.

```
<div id="button" style="display:none;">YOUR BUTTON</div>

<input class="opc1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input class="opc2" type="checkbox" value="2" />

$('.opc1').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#button').show();
  }else{
   $('#button').show();
  }
});
$('.opc2').on("click",function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#button').hide();
    //Also you can use $('#button').remove(); but if you need show this before don't remove.
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't use id bro I use class is it the same? <div class='continuar' ><input type="button" onclick="siguiente()" value="Continuar"  class="boton" > </div>

Comment: is not the same, but if is just an element is better use id.

ID = SINGULAR ELEMENT
CLASS = PLURAL ELEMENTS

The checkbox should be id
Just replace the "#" for "."

Comment: It worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean, but if i understand you correct you looking for something like this:

```css
button{
  display:none;
}
input:checked + input:checked + button{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
Please accept the terms of Conditions<input type="checkbox">
and the License Agreement<input type="checkbox">, thanks!
<button>Thanks, proceed &raquo;</button>
```